# Differences Between PowerShell and C# when Enumerating a Collection

Tags: c#, powershell, enumeration

Here is a simple scenario in C#:

```
var intList = new List<int>();
intList.Add(4);
intList.Add(7);
intList.Add(2);
intList.Add(9);
intList.Add(6);

foreach (var num in intList)
{
  if (num == 9)
  {
    intList.Remove(num);
    Console.WriteLine("Removed item: " + num);
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Number is: " + num);
}
```

This throws an `InvalidOperationException` because I am modifying the collection while enumerating it.

Now consider similar PowerShell code:

```
$intList = 4, 7, 2, 9, 6

foreach ($num in $intList)
{
  if ($num -eq 9)
  {
    $intList = @($intList | Where-Object {$_ -ne $num})
    Write-Host "Removed item: " $num
  }

  Write-Host "Number is: " $num
}

Write-Host $intList
```

This script actually removes the number 9 from the list! No exceptions thrown.

Now, I know the C# example uses a List object while the PowerShell example uses an array, but how does PowerShell enumerate a collection that will be modified during the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is already given by @Sean, I am just providing the code which shows that the original collection is not changed during `foreach`: it enumerates through the original collection and there is no contradiction therefore.

```
# original array
$intList = 4, 7, 2, 9, 6

# make another reference to be used for watching of $intList replacement
$anotherReferenceToOriginal = $intList

# prove this: it is not a copy, it is a reference to the original:
# change [0] in the original, see the change through its reference
$intList[0] = 5
$anotherReferenceToOriginal[0] # it is 5, not 4

# foreach internally calls GetEnumerator() on $intList once;
# this enumerator is for the array, not the variable $intList
foreach ($num in $intList)
{
    [object]::ReferenceEquals($anotherReferenceToOriginal, $intList)
    if ($num -eq 9)
    {
        # this creates another array and $intList after assignment just contains
        # a reference to this new array, the original is not changed, see later;
        # this does not affect the loop enumerator and its collection
        $intList = @($intList | Where-Object {$_ -ne $num})
        Write-Host "Removed item: " $num
        [object]::ReferenceEquals($anotherReferenceToOriginal, $intList)
    }

    Write-Host "Number is: " $num
}

# this is a new array, not the original
Write-Host $intList

# this is the original, it is not changed
Write-Host $anotherReferenceToOriginal
```

Output:

```
5
True
Number is:  5
True
Number is:  7
True
Number is:  2
True
Removed item:  9
False
Number is:  9
False
Number is:  6
5 7 2 6
5 7 2 9 6
```

We can see that `$intList` is changed when we "remove an item". It only means that this variable now contains a reference to a new array, it is the variable changed, not the array. The loop continues enumeration of the original array which is not changed and `$anotherReferenceToOriginal` still contains a reference to it.

Comment: Marking this as answer because it explains things fully. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The **foreach** construct evaluates the list to completion and stores the result in a temporary variable before it starts iterating over it. When you do that actual removal you are updating **$intList** to reference a new list. In other words in actually doing something like this under the hood:

```
$intList = 4, 7, 2, 9, 6

$tempList=$intList
foreach ($num in $tempList)
{
  if ($num -eq 9)
  {
    $intList = @($intList | Where-Object {$_ -ne $num})
    Write-Host "Removed item: " $num
  }

  Write-Host "Number is: " $num
}

Write-Host $intList
```

Your call to:

```
$intList = @($intList | Where-Object {$_ -ne $num})
```

Actually creates a completely new list with the value removed.

If you change the removal logic to remove the last item in the list (6) then I think you'll find that it's still printed even though you think it's removed because of the temporary copy.

Comment: JaredPar's answer indicates that the foreach construct does NOT create a temporary list copy.

Comment: @Greg: No, JaredPar uses an ArrayList. There's nothing in the Powershell code to indicate that the list is a List<> or ArrayList, that's an implementation detail.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Powershell to know: is the "foreach construct" you reference in your answer from the line `foreach ($num in $intList)` or the line that contains `Where-Object {$_ -ne $num}`. I had assumed the former.

Comment: I believe @Greg was referring to the statement "foreach evaluates the list to completion and stores the result in a temporary variable". For example, `$a = 1..3; foreach( $n in $a ) { $a[-1] = -1; $n }` will print out `1, 2, -1`, not `1, 2, 3` as would appear from a temporary copy.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you're not comparing equivalent code samples.  In the Powershell sample you are creating a new list vs modifying the list in place as is done in the C# sample.  Here is a sample which is closer in functionality to the original C# one

```
$intList = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
$intList.Add(4)
$intList.Add(7)
$intList.Add(2)
$intList.Add(9)
$intList.Add(6)

foreach ($num in $intList) { 
  if ($num -eq 9) { 
    $intList.Remove($num)
    Write-Host "Removed item: " $num 
  } 

  Write-Host "Number is: " $num 
} 

Write-Host $intList
```

And when run it produces the same error

```
Number is:  4
Number is:  7
Number is:  2
Removed item:  9
Number is:  9
An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Collection was modifi
ed; enumeration operation may not execute..
At C:\Users\jaredpar\temp\test.ps1:10 char:8
+ foreach <<<<  ($num in $intList)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Collecti...numeratorSi
   mple:ArrayListEnumeratorSimple) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration

4 7 2 6
```